# uiBootstrap timepicker stays one hour behind

Tags: angularjs, timepicker

I am using ui-bootstrap timepicker and the time on the scope variable is always one hour behind the time that is displayed on the picker. what is causing it and how can I get rid of it. I need to store the correct time not the time thats one hour behind.

For example when the time on time-picker is :
16 : 12

i get to see on console:
Time is: "2016-05-26T15:12:34.403Z"

I followed very basic code for the ui-bootstrap timepicker. Can anyone explain how can I store the correct time in my variable.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your browsers timezone settings vs your servers? Maybe something related to that?

Comment: how do i check my browser 's timezone setting's also ..if the time zone settings are different for both of them..is there a way to ensure that they are same for both the browser and server where ever this app runs.